# Symfony 2 - No route found for "GET /videotheque"

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I need some help because I didn't succeed in finding the source of my route problem.

Here is my `routing.yml`:

```
gstyle39VideothequeBundle:
    resource: "@gstyle39VideothequeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /videotheque
```

The `routing.yml` in `VideothequeBundle/Resources/config/`:

```
VideothequeBundle_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: gstyle39VideothequeBundle:Videotheque:index }
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace gstyle39\VideothequeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class VideothequeController extends Controller
{    
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new Response("Kikoo");
    }
}
```

For my part I did a "cache:clear", a "router:debug" which detected my route:

```
VideothequeBundle_homepage ANY /videotheque/
```

I also manually deleted the folder `app/cache`...

Comment: As `router:debug` is outputting, you must append a slash at the end of your url.

Comment: Are you missing the ending `/`? Your route should be `http://yourpage.local/videotheque/` (mind the ending slash).

Comment: I have tested but the error is still here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you didn't add routing definition in application global routing.yml (app/config/routing.yml).

Look at my routing definitions in https://github.com/drupalmk/Jobeeto

Comment: Hi, I added the routing definition but the error appears again

Comment: COuld you provide all config you have?

Comment: I have reinstalled Symfony2, and I have coded again all my routes and the controller... and finally it works.
Thx for your time.